# Does the Taliban rape gay men?

Tags: afghanistan

> When Hanan met the men, they raped and beat him, Afghan LGBTQ rights activist Artemis Akbary told ITV.

> Akbary told the outlet that Taliban fighters are likely to do this again.

> "They'll make a profile account and deceive LGBT+ people by pretending they're a member of the community," he said.

https://news.yahoo.com/taliban-raped-beat-gay-man-081611760.html

https://www.independent.co.uk/asia/south-asia/taliban-homophobic-attack-lgbt-afghanistan-b1911848.html

https://www.freepressjournal.in/world/afghanistan-tricked-into-meeting-gay-man-raped-and-beaten-by-taliban-militants

Not only is it being claimed that some Taliban raped a man, it is also being implied that this is a Taliban policy. This despite their ideology allegedly condemning homosexuality. How is this possible??

Comment: Rape of captives is often not related to general sexual preferences and activity, and is further well documented in many cases. "Prison rape" is practically a meme.

Comment: IIRC sodomy is prohibited, so I wouldn't be surprised if they [used an object](https://www.rferl.org/a/russia-gay-rape-uzbek-community-homophobia/25105544.html) or something like that. The story you linked is rather short on details on the rape angle. (It's a somewhat popular punishment method in [the wider region](https://www.advocate.com/world/2020/9/08/teen-who-criticized-chechnyas-leader-forced-film-self-rape).)

Comment: The much more standard Taliban punishment of olde was crush a wall on them http://web.archive.org/web/20210818123911/https://www.latimes.com/archives/la-xpm-2002-apr-03-mn-35991-story.html ; http://web.archive.org/web/20210822040910/https://www.nytimes.com/1999/01/16/world/execution-by-taliban-crushed-under-wall.html

Comment: In a recent interview "Gul Rahim, a Taliban judge in a province in central Afghanistan" said that the punishment hadn't changed  https://www.dw.com/en/afghanistan-lgbtq-people-fear-for-their-lives-under-taliban-rule/a-59144208 Full interview [here](https://www.bild.de/politik/international/bild-international/this-taliban-judge-orders-stoning-hanging-hands-chopped-of-77067554.bild.html) although it doesn't have that much on this issue.

Comment: Apparently the Afghan version is to use a rifle barrel https://www.rferl.org/a/afghanistan-dostum-accused-abduction-rape-former-governor/28176244.html

Comment: Considering that rape in general is far more about power and dominance than it is about sex, I don't think this is too far fetched